# Does connecting a USB keyboard to a PS2 port with a USB to PS2 converter reduce its latency?

Tags: usb, keyboard, mouse, ps2, ps2-keyboard

I plugged my old PS2 keyboard while getting my USB keyboard clean and dry, and I think I feel it has lower latency...

Apparently PS2 is just better than USB, but I'm used to the physical aspect of the USB keyboard.

I use Windows.